# How can I put a multiple calculation in a vim text document?

Tags: vim, macros, numbers, calculator

I would like to insert the output of multiple calculations into my text document:

```
2**3 = (the result)   
2**4 =         
..   
2**30 =
```

(** = exponential)
Can anyone help me?

P.S.:
It would be nice to have a kind of immediate scripting in vim without using .vimrc, 
just to do quick operations

p.e.
`for i in range (3,30)

  print "2**".i."=".2**i

  endfor`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a `for...loop` like this:

```
:for i in range(3, 30) | call setline(i-2, printf('2**%d = %d', i, float2nr(pow(2, i)))) | endfor
```

Another way is to redirect messages to a file:

```
:redir! >output.txt
:for i in range(3, 30) | echo printf('2**%d = %d', i, float2nr(pow(2, i))) | endfor
:redir END
:e output.txt
```

Comment: wow.. I didn't know that I could do it with a for..loop in the command line. Thank you. Can you please tell me a bit more what it exactly does?

Comment: What would be the command p.e. if I want to multiply i*i? 
`:for i in range(3, 30) | call setline(i-2, printf('%d*%d = %d', i, i*i))` gives an error.

Comment: `Insufficient arguments for printf()`. Try `printf('%d*%d = %d', i, i, i*i)`

Comment: yes! I tried to do above in a macro but this is much easier. Thank  you Kev. I wish I could insert the output where the cursor is but I asked too much. It seems VIM has only two command setline + append isn't it?

Comment: You can `redir` the message to a file(`ouput.txt`)/register(`x`), then read(`:r output.txt`) the file/put the register(`"xp`).

Comment: @Remonn:  Consider also `call append('.', map(range(3, 30), '"2**".v:val." = ".string(pow(2,v:val))'))` or `call append('.', map(range(3, 30), 'printf("2**%d = %.0f", v:val, pow(2,v:val))'))`.

Comment: @ib. Do you know how to create a double loop using `call append('.', map(range(3, 30), 'printf("2**%d = %.0f", v:val, pow(2,v:val))'))`?

Comment: @Remonn: This approach would work as well. Note, however, that unlike the for-loop approach, all of the strings to be inserted are populated in memory in their entirety before they are actually appended.

Answer (score 3):

If you prefer Python, and your vim is compiled with the support, you can utilize it:

```
:py import vim
:py for i in range(3, 30): vim.current.buffer.append("2**%d = %d" % (i, 2**i))
```

For more complex feats you may want to write a block of code instead of oneliners. This is a way to do it, it just isn't very convenient to do on the interactive command line, but possible:

```
:py << EOF
import vim
for i in range(3, 30):
  for j in range(1, 3):
    vim.current.buffer.append("{}x{}".format(i, j))
EOF
```

More complex stuff is meant to be written in script files and source them at need.

Comment: Is it possible to create a double loop in python (using vim)? This doesn't work `py for i in range(3, 30): for j in range (1, 10): vim.current.buffer.append("2**%d = %d" % (i, 2**j))`

Comment: @Remonn: python doesn't grok that kind of oneliners. Use the block notation as I edited in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can execute math in vim using the special register `=`, for example if you type in insert mode

```
2+3=<C-R>=2+3<CR>
```

you get

```
2+3=5
```

P.S. `<C-R>` means CTRL+r, `<CR>` means pressing return.

Comment: Simple and effective!

Answer (score 1):

The following also works

write some lines, of say python

```
total = 0.0
for i in range(10):
   total += i*i
print total
```

then select the lines visually (with `shift-v`) and type 
`:!python`. What you should actually see is `:'<,'>!python`
then the lines you typed should be replaced by the output of the lines in python.